# Auto link source code downloaded by Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Sorry if this question is duplicated but I have searched for a while and couldn't find the answer.

I use Android Studio and Gradle to develop my app, gralde will auto download source code from maven but then inside Android Studio it's said that **"Sources Not Found"** and I have to drag drop or select the source files directly. This is very troublesome. Is there anyway that AS auto link the sources downloaded with the class, and when I ctrl + click on the class it will open the source file directly?

**Edit:** Some libraries like ButterKnife I can view source code directly, but others like MaterialEditext I have to select the source file manually.

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.0.3'
```

[image]

ButterKnife can be found in External Library while MaterialEditext isn't. I don't know why.

Comment: I am not really sure I understand. You want to view the source code of the dependency from inside Android Studio? That should not be a problem. I don't know about ctrl + click, but on my Mac I can jump to any class definition - whether it is in a dependency or not - with ⌘ + B.

Comment: What's strange here is that some libraries like ButterKnife I can view source code directly, but others like MaterialEditext I have to select the source file manually.

Answer (score 0):

Not every module you want can be selected automatically. Only those you can find in `dependencies` could be imported by `Gradle`. Take a look here:right-click at your project --->`Open Module Settings`--->`Modules`--->`Dependencies`--->`Plus`--->`Library Dependency`, and then you can select one `Library Dependency`. And then it will be added into your project by `Gradle`. Most importantly, **What You Can See Is What You Can Get.** If you can't see the module you want, maybe you need to download it somewhere else.

Comment: Actually, all libraries is imported by Gradle, I do not add any .jar file. What I concern is that two libraries added by Gradle, one source can be added automatically, one cannot although I can find two source files in Gradle Folder.

Comment: the second you can find in `dependencies`?

Comment: Both can be found in dependencies :(

Comment: You can try with this:

compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.0.3'